# Twisted single connection server

Tags: python-3.x, server, twisted

I'm a twisted newbie.

What I want is to enforce a single connection at the server side. Basically I want new connections to wait to process data until the first connection is complete. I don't want it to reject new connections, I just want the connections to be processed serially by the server.

The reason for this is that the process on the server side is dependent on the data from before. The data needs to be finished processing before the next data from the new connection should be processed. The data will be processed by sending the data to another server so it could take a while.

I know I can check the number of connections at connectionMade and go to sleep and check again. I need the data to be processed in the order in which it arrived, so I would need to add another counter that tracked the position of the connection as well. This seems like a very clunky solution. Is there another way to do this?

This is the quoteserver.py

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class QuoteProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.numConnections += 1

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Number of active connections: %d" % (
        self.factory.numConnections,)
        print "> Received: ``%s''\n> Sending: ``%s''" % (
        data, self.getQuote())
        self.transport.write(self.getQuote())
        self.updateQuote(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.numConnections -= 1

    def getQuote(self):
        return self.factory.quote

    def updateQuote(self, quote):
        self.factory.quote = quote

class QuoteFactory(Factory):
    numConnections = 0
    def __init__(self, quote=None):
        self.quote = quote or "An apple a day keeps the doctor away"
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return QuoteProtocol(self)

reactor.listenTCP(8000, QuoteFactory())
reactor.run()
```

This is the quoteclient.py

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class QuoteProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendQuote()

    def sendQuote(self):
        self.transport.write(self.factory.quote)

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Received quote:", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

class QuoteClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def __init__(self, quote):
        self.quote = quote

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return QuoteProtocol(self)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection failed:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        maybeStopReactor()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print 'connection lost:', reason.getErrorMessage()
        maybeStopReactor()

def maybeStopReactor():
    global quote_counter
    quote_counter -= 1
    if not quote_counter:
        reactor.stop()

quotes = [
 "You snooze you lose",
 "The early bird gets the worm",
 "Carpe diem"
]
quote_counter = len(quotes)

for quote in quotes:
    reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 8000, QuoteClientFactory(quote))
reactor.run()
```

Comment: You left a question out of your question.  You said what you want to happen and you dropped a pile of code.  Now, what's stopping you from doing what you want?

Comment: I want a way to ensure that a single connection is processing data at one time server side. I know I can do this by using the self.factory.numConnections counter and sleep. I was hoping there are a *better* way than using sleep and a counter for the active connections.